# ReactJS Typescript Argument of type '{ keyPrefix: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, typescript, i18next

There are only a few similar questions for this and the solution in both of them is not working in my case. Here is a snippet of the code which is giving this error:

[image: error in the homepage typescript file]

homepage.tsx file:

```
export const CTASection = () => {
  const {t, i18n} = useTranslation( {keyPrefix:("homepage.ctaSection")} )

  return (
    <StyledSection>
      <CTAContainer>
        <Header>{t('Header')}</Header>
        <Subtitle>
           Play and learn <i>risk-free</i>. Prove your knowledge, speculate and
          win!
        </Subtitle>
.....
```

my JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "homepage": {
      "ctaSection": {
        "header": "some thing"
      }
    }
  }
  
]
```

I am actually trying to use this content of the JSON file to be displayed on the homepage in the header section, and what I am actually getting is the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option is on the second parameter according to the [Doc](https://react.i18next.com/latest/usetranslation-hook).

```
const { t } = useTranslation('', { keyPrefix: 'homepage.ctaSection' });
```

Comment: still gives the same error

Comment: Try follow the documentation and see if you can get `useTranslation()` work first.

Comment: main error resolved, thanks @windmaomao, but it doesn't extract the content of the JSON file, rather just displays [ homepage.ctaSection.Header ] on the homepage

Comment: I have followed the documentation as closely as I can, but I keep getting " missing key " error in the console, and no solution have worked so far, would you mind helping me out?

Answer (score 1):

try the following:

```
const { t } = useTranslation('homepage', { keyPrefix: 'ctaSection' });
```

Comment: Thanks William for your solution, I'm not working on the project anymore, hope it might help others.